# Confused about angular momentum conservation from deflection angle derivation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, orbital-motion

I have started going through A. Zee's "Einstien Gravity in  Nutshell" after a good number of years away from studying physics (perhaps too many) and I have been stuck on a derivation that I would appreciate some assitance in.

In the solution to Exercise 3 in Chapter I.1, Zee finishes the Newtonian derivation of the deflection angle of starlight from a large mass as $\Delta \theta = \frac{2GM}{l\sqrt{2\epsilon}}$ where $l$ and $\epsilon$ are the angular momentum and energy per unit mass, respectively. He then goes on to define the deflection angle:

> ...in terms of the impact paramater $b$ definied by saying that as $x \rightarrow \infty$, the light ray moves along a path specified by $y=b$. Translating into polar coordinates, we have, as $r \rightarrow \infty$, from (9) $b \simeq r\theta$, from (18) $\dot{r}^2 \simeq 2\epsilon$. Using (15) and $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \frac{\dot{r}}{\dot{\theta}}$, we determine $l = b\sqrt{2\epsilon}$.

(9): $y = r\sin\theta$
(15): $\dot{\theta} = \frac{l}{r^2}$
(18): $\frac{1}{2}\dot{r}^2 +v(r) = \epsilon$

**I am stuck on this conclusion as with $l = b\sqrt{2\epsilon}$,  wouldn't that imply that $l$, the angular momentum, increases as $b$ increases??** This doesn't make sense to me as how could this "object" increase in momentum if the only thing that is changing is the object traveling farther from the large mass?

As I said, it has been a good number of years since I studied physics so I am obviously rusty, but if anyone could point me in the right direction or give me some explanation of where my reasoning is wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: It is correct. If you draw a straight line across the page corresponding to the mathematical assumption that there is no gravitational interaction and thus the initial motion just continues unaffected, then the shortest perpendicular distance from the line to the black hole centre is $b$, and the angular momentum is clearly $\ell = b \times p$ where $p$ is the linear momentum. i.e. by definition of angular momentum, it would increase as $b$ increases. This is a general phenomenon and has nothing to do with gravitation. All (non-spin) angular momentum is defined with the same behaviour.